# A never ending puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**What answer is hidden below?**

---

```
                     Translate: [59111519920519195181718113131201]
       
                   

                                         after.

                   [16th]:   (5)(1 11)(1 11)(1)(6 32)(5)(1 4)(1 2)(1)
                                     
                   [21th]:  (2 19)(2 11)(19 2)(2 5)(19)(22)(2 3)(2 7)
```

Comment: I have about two dozen ideas about this (which might be enough for a partial answer later), but the (6 32) is really throwing me off as it doesn't seem to fit any of them. Could you please confirm there are no typoes?

Comment: @Bass Yes just checked, no typoes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This was quite a journey, with several "a-ha!" moments required to reach the conclusion. I left in some of the memo notes I wrote to myself while solving, hope it makes the thought processes a bit easier to follow. (In addition to hopelessly cluttering the answer up). In any case, here's what I got:

---

Starting with the "Translate" line, we can split it into numbers between 1 and 26, so we get (after some considerable guesswork and fiddling around with the connections of the various ones):

> ```
>  5 9 11 15 19 9 20 5 19 19 5 18 1 7 18 1 13 13 1 20 1
>  E I K  O  S  I T  E  S  S E  R A G  R A  M  M A  T A
> ```

The [A1Z26](https://www.dcode.fr/letter-number-cipher) interpretation doesn't seem to make too much sense, although it definitely looks like a natural language. (Because as long as it didn't, we'd continue tweaking the "is 113 one-thirteen or eleven-three?" options.)

Sounding it out it might actually be

> Greek transcribed with the English alphabet

And indeed that turns out to be the case:

> "ΕΙΚΟΣΙ ΤΕΣΣΕΡΑ ΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΑ" means "Twenty Four Letters" in Greek.

The "16th" and "21st" are then very likely references to the (topically never ending)

> mathematical constants $\pi$ (3.14..) and $\phi$ (1.618..), which are respectively the 16th and 21st letters of the 24-letter Greek alphabet.

The square brackets kind of suggest indexing (at least to someone with a programming background), and the "`after.`" might be an instruction to ignore the part before the decimal point. But how on earth would one index with two numbers in parens?

Maybe it's a simple substitution cipher? Sure looks like one, because of all the repeating elements:

```
              [16th]:   (5)(1 11)(1 11)(1)(6 32)(5)(1 4)(1 2)(1)
                         I     M     M  E     D  I    A    T  E

              [21th]:  (2 19)(2 11)(19 2)(2 5)(19)(22)(2 3)(2 7)     
                           L     U     N    C   H   B    O    X
```

Yeah, that could work. Doesn't seem to make a lot of sense though, and didn't help with the indexing either.

After verifying with OP that the 32 (in the middle of the first row) isn't a typo, we kinda know we're not dealing with any direct alphabetic ciphers, which don't reach numbers that big. But what else could they be? After a good while of staring at the screen and pondering the constants hinted at in the puzzle, I finally figured out why OP would put such a number in the puzzle:

32 is actually

> the *position of the **first zero** in the decimal expansion of pi*!
>
>  Now it all makes sense: the two-number groups are, quite simply, just *two digit numbers*!

So let's replace each number with

> that many-eth digit of pi (3.14159 26535 89793 23846 26433 83279 50288...), then read any pairs as a single number, finally translating to English with A1Z26:
>
> ```
>  [16th]:   (5)(1 11)(1 11)(1)(6 32)(5)(1 4)(1 2)(1)
>  [16th]:   (9)(1  8)(1  8)(1)(2  0)(9)(1 5)(1 4)(1)
>             9    18    18  1    20  9   15   14  1
>             I     R     R  A     T  I    O    N  A
> ```

And repeating for the other line but this time indexing

> the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio): 1.61803 39887 49894 84820 45868...
>
> ```
>   [21th]:  (2 19)(2 11)(19 2)(2 5)(19)(22)(2 3)(2 7)
>   [21th]:  (1  2)(1  4)(2  1)(1 3)( 2)( 5)(1 8)(1 9)
>               12    14    21   13   2   5   18   19
>                L     N     U    M   B   E    R    S
> ```

we get the final answer of

> **IRRATIONAL NUMBERS**,

which, as the title suggests, are indeed "never ending" when written in decimal. (Or in any other integer base, for that matter.) Nice!

Comment: You got it :) And yes the "after." just meant "after decimal point". Well done!

Comment: @Prim3numbah nice red herring on the immediate lunchbox? how did you even do that, haha

Comment: @justhalf no need to do anything, really: the [unicity distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicity_distance) for an English language substitution cipher is well over 20 letters; any message shorter than that is likely to have spurious solutions like the lunchbox one above.

Comment: @Bass Ah, I had assumed you substituted the numbers to letters by a common shift. Apparently it's arbitrary, then it's much more likely, I agree.

Comment: @justhalf applying a common shift would be a bit trickier, seeing how some of the numbers are actually pairs 

Comment: I thought you only used the second number (since you put the letters below the second number) -- was actually one of my confusion reading that part. So you considered a pair as one unit of substitution?

Comment: @justhalf  Sure, and that turned out to be the correct thing to do in the end. Of course, I did try using just the second number, but that ran into a problem with the 32, as mentioned somewhere near the middle part of the messy story :-)

Comment: Yeah, that was not intentional. I actually didn't get that part myself, instead I thought I would get an alternative answer :D but then I scrolled down to see that the correct answer was given.